# I wanna make a code that has nice structural. But I can't

Tags: javascript, function, class, prototype, literals

I wanna make a code that has nice structural like this:
https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/dist/js/swiper.jquery.js#L67

So, I made this. but it doesn't works.
http://jsbin.com/xiralokola/edit?html,js,output

```js
// friends.js

$(function () {
  'use strict';
  
  function Friends() {
    var settings = {
      name: null,
      age: null,
      gender: null,
      printTarget: null
    };
  }
  
  Friends.prototype = {
    getInfo: function () {
      var subject = (this.gender == 'female') ? 'She' : 'He',
          html = '<p>';
      html += '\'' + this.name + '\' is my friend.';
      html += subject + ' is' + this.age + ' years old.';
      html += '</p>';
      
      this.printTarget.append(html);
      return html;
    }
  };
  
  window.Friends = Friends;
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Friends</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <h1>Friends</h1>
  <div id="print"></div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <script src="friends.js"></script>
  <script>
    var myFriend = new Friends({
      name: 'Hee-sook',
      age: 15,
      gender: 'female', 
      printTarget: $('#print')
    });
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

I think there are problems near the 'var settings'.
But I don't know how to fix it.
Please help me.

Comment: Was it functionally working before making structural changes?

Comment: Now I added `<script src="friends.js"></script>` on HTML. Is this right what you mean?

Comment: you're passing in an argument on `new Friends` - but `Friends` takes no arguments, so, the object you pass in is pointless ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[try this](http://jsbin.com/tucabexawi/1/edit?html,js,output)

you had 3 issues:

1. you've tried to call an instance of Friends before it was defined ($(function) should be on the html in that case and not on the js file)

should be:

```
<script>
$(function () {
var myFriend = new Friends({
  name: 'Hee-sook',
  age: 15,
  gender: 'female', 
  printTarget: $('#print')
});

  });
```

2. you didn't pass the settings object to the constructor, should be:

   ```
   function Friends(settings) {
       $.extend(this,settings);
   }
   ```
3. you didn't call the getInfo() on the instance:

   ```
   myFriend.getInfo();
   ```

Comment: Wow~ thank you for your kind description!!
http://jsbin.com/wahazilece/edit?html,js,output